# Symfony & Phantom JS Bundle - Routing Error

Tags: php, html, symfony, phantomjs, rasterize

I am using [this](https://github.com/Padam87/RasterizeBundle) Bundle to convert HTML to PDF files.

The actual conversion works, but I have a problem understanding the routing.

Here is my code:

```
/**
 * @Route("/formulare/selbstauskunft/{keycode}", name="saPrint")
 */
public function saPrintAction(Request $request, $keycode)
{


    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $sa = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Selfinfo')->findOneBy(array(
        'keycode' => $keycode,
    ));

    if(count($sa) > 0){

        $response = new Response(
            $this->get('padam87_rasterize.rasterizer')->rasterize(
                $this->renderView('default/formSAPrint.html.twig', array(
                    'selfinfo' => $sa,
                ))
            ),
            200, [
                'Content-Type'          => 'application/pdf',
                'Content-Disposition'   => 'attachment; filename="my.pdf"'
            ]
        );

        return $response;

    }else{
        return new Response("fail");
    }
}
```

The bundle creates 2 files, `rasterize-UNIQUEID.html` and `rasterize-UNIQUEID.pdf`. The html file contains the correct output.
After the creation of the html file in `/bundles/padam87rasterize/temp/` the second part of the script opens this file via an url call [here](https://github.com/Padam87/RasterizeBundle/blob/master/Rasterizer.php#L68).
Unfortunately the actual rendered page is a symfony error page, saying:

> No route found for `GET /bundles/padam87rasterize/temp/rasterize-UNIQUEID.html`

What do I have to set in order to render the html file?

Answer (score 0):

I think you actually have to create a separare route to render the html. As far as I can tell the `rasterize` function generates a pdf from the temporary html file (The key word being temporary).